# What opt in rate can be achieved with Apple’s iOS14 ATT prompt?

Tags: ios, permissions, privacy, ios14, att

As of iOS14 Apple require a permission prompt to use IDFA for advertising.

Can anyone who has implemented the App Tracking Transparency (ATT) framework already share rough percentages of users who tap Allow vs. Don’t Allow?

Some articles have suggested around 20% but I wanted to find actual feedback from live iOS apps.

It can obviously be anonymous but any ballpark figures and industry/genre would be very much appreciated, so app developers can get an idea of what impact this will have on advertising revenue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Developers forecast that as little as 10 to 13 per cent of Facebook users will opt-in to tracking if given the choice."
Source: https://www.the-sun.com/lifestyle/tech/2253930/facebook-notification-iphone-ad-tracking-apple-privacy-update/